# RxJava2 concat operator doesn't return appropriate stream

Tags: android, repository, rx-java2, android-room

In order to build my repository, I am retrieving 2 streams of data from Local Database and from remote API. I am trying to access the remote stream only if the `mQuakesLocalDataSource` has no items by using the `concat` operator as shown in many examples.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Single<List<Quake>> getQuakes(){
    return Single.concat(mQuakesLocalDataSource.getQuakes(),
                            mQuakesRemoteDataSource.getQuakes())
                              .first(dummyList);
}
```

The issue I am facing is that `mQuakesRemoteDataSource` never returns a stream while `mQuakesLocalDataSource` is empty, therefore I am not  having any data result. I have tested `mQuakesRemoteDataSource` in isolation and without the `concat` operator it seems to be retrieving its appropriate stream.

**Why is this happening?**

`mQuakesLocalDataSource` is based on Room and so therefore it should emit its stream and then complete, so it's not possible that the local source would emit a never-ending stream like `SQLbrite` does.

I have tried variations of this operator like `concatArray` and the result was the same, no data is being retrieved whatsoever.

An interesting note would be the fact that while debugging, I noticed that both `mQuakesLocalDataSource` and `mQuakesRemoteDataSource` `get` methods are triggered when passed into `concat` operator, before reaching the `first()` line. Shouldn't `concat` evaluate sources one by one (and filter the current one) in the presence of `first` operator?

I have also tried adding a filter with a `Predicate` in order to cache data into the Local Data Source,  as below:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Single<List<Quake>> getQuakes() {
    return Single.concat(mQuakesLocalDataSource.getQuakes(),
            mQuakesRemoteDataSource.getQuakes()).filter(new Predicate<List<Quake>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(List<Quake> quakes) throws Exception {
            boolean isValid = quakes != null && !quakes.isEmpty();

            // save items to local data source
            if (isValid) saveQuakes(quakes);

            return isValid;
        }
    }).first(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

The result was the same, no data is being retrieved.

Comment: why not to use `merge` instead of `concat`?

Comment: `merge` operator would emit the observables in order of whichever source would return it’s observable first, so there might be the case when the remote source would retrieve faster than the local one, therefore breaking the business rules I am trying to impose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning an empty list in `Single` doesn't make the `Single` empty, thus `first` will correctly stop at the first item, the empty list, never calling the remote source. You have to decide on the item via `flatMap` whether or not to resume with the remote source instead of concat:

```java
mQuakesLocalDataSource.getQuakes()
.flatMap(list -> {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return mQuakesRemoteDataSource.getQuakes();
    }
    return Single.just(list);
})
```

Comment: Why have I seen then so many examples of repositories (some with Room) having such implementation that I described in the question? I can leave numerous links of the example

Comment: Don't worry, all of those examples you saw are suboptimal as per specified in https://youtu.be/8ni8RY__WeU?t=28m56s by the AAC team lead Yigit (one of the main creators of Room, LiveData, etc)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce That is a very good point - making the disk the single source of truth.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Is the solution provided by akarnokd following the ssot principle? I think that feeding the UI the remote retrieved data is exactly what that video is not encouraging, is this right?